# Why my queryset filter for creating electricity bill is not working?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I was working on a project in which a user creates some members(model) and their electricity bills (this is also a model) but when I'm applying queryset to ElectricityForm  it's showing errors.

[KeyError at /bills/electricity/create/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gioWc.png)

**my members/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class Member(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),      on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="members")
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=252, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
   phone_no = PhoneNumberField()

   def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

**my electricity_bills/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from members.models import Member
import uuid
import datetime
class ElectricityBill(models.Model): 
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="electricity_bills" )
     id_member = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     k_no = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     last_date = models.DateField()
     state = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False , choices=state_choices,     default="Rajasthan")
     month = models.CharField(choices=months, default="January", max_length=10)
     year = models.CharField(choices=years, default="2022", max_length=4)
     amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     email_send = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     is_email_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.member)
```

**my electricity_bill/views.py**

```
class ElectricityBillCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView): 
   model = ElectricityBill
   template_name = 'bills/electricity/bill_create.html'
   form_class = ElectricityForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('ebills_list')
```

**my electricity_bills/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import ElectricityBill
from members.models import Member
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class ElectricityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(ElectricityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['member'].queryset = Member.objects.filter(
        created_by=self.request.user)

member = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.all())
k_no = forms.CharField()
id_member = forms.CharField()

class Meta:
    model = ElectricityBill
    fields =  ("member", "k_no", "id_member", "state", "last_date", "month", "year", "amount", "email_send")
```

If you know how to solve this issue, please tell me I'm tired out of this

Comment: Error on line `self.request = kwargs.pop('request')` is telling you that ElectrictyForm kwargs dictionary doesn't have `request` key. request data can be accessed in view methods

Answer (score 2):

Override [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) in your CreateView subclass to pass additional keyword arguments to your form's `__init__` method

To pass the current `request`:

```
class ElectricityBillCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    
    ...
     
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```